# name a session with variable

Tags: php, session-variables

Well what i want to do is , fetch a value from a database and asign it to a session name something like this

```
$_SESSION[$fetch[0]['name']]=some_value;
```

i dont know if im able to do that but it'll be quite usefull to me.

Comment: As long as the session exists (`session_start()` was called somewhere above this), your code will create a key-value pair that will persist during the session.  The key will be `$fetch[0]['name']` and will retrieve `some_value` until you specify otherwise. What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes you can do that, but i would advise you to set a static value such as:

```
$_SESSION["name"] = $fetch[0]['name'];
```

and then you can just use `$_SESSION["name"]` to get the value.

everything written in the php is classed as hard code, you should be aware that setting dynamic content as array keys are usually unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

Why not? As long as you can still use the value that is returned by `$fetch[0]['name']`...

Comment: Unless there are duplicates.  Then you might want some higher-level translation logic between the application and the session.